# Generate condition for selecting rows in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

For the dataframe df, I am selecting the rows that have True values either in column 'a' or 'b'.

```
>>> df
Out[127]: 
       a      b
0  False  False
1   True   True
2   True  False
>>> con = (df['a'] == True) | (df['b'] == True)
>>> con
Out[129]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
>>> df[con]
Out[130]: 
      a      b
1  True   True
2  True  False
```

There are only two columns in the dataframe. For the actual code, the number of such columns is a variable. How can the condition `con` be generated on-the-fly?

Say, when df has 26 columns from *a* through *z*, I want something like

```
>>> con = (df['a'] == True) | (df['b'] == True) | ... (df['y'] == True) | (df['z'] == True)
```

which I can use to get the desired rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True]+[False]*5, size=(6,5)), columns=list("abcde"))
>>> df
       a      b      c      d      e
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False
2  False  False   True  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False   True
5  False  False  False  False  False
>>> df.any(axis=1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
>>> df[df.any(axis=1)]
       a      b      c      d      e
1  False  False   True  False  False
2  False  False   True  False  False
4  False  False  False  False   True
```

And as always you can use `df.loc[df.any(axis=1)]` if you want to ensure you have a handle on the original.

Comment: It solves the problem. Also, is it possible to generate the `con` variable to feed into `df[con]` as originally posted? Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: @user832: your `con` is simply `df.any(axis=1)`, basically because `x or y or z` is the same as `any([x,y,z])`.  You can write `con = df.any(axis=1)`, if you like

Comment: Can a program automatically create an expression and assign to a variable as in python str.format() : `'{x} or {y} or {z}'.format(x, y, z)` where the number of params in format() is variable and the expression is not a string while assigning to variable `con`?

Comment: I'm tempted to say no, because this is almost always a bad idea, but yes, it can be done.

Comment: Could you please share the terms associated? Curious to learn why it is a bad idea.